# magento 2 system.log error - Invalid template file: in module Infortis_UltraMegamenu

Tags: magento2, error, frontend-error, system.log

from system.log

```
[2019-05-10 08:48:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'categories_searchresult.phtml' in module: 'Infortis_UltraMegamenu' block's name: 'sidebar.main_schedule_block0' [] []
```

from exception.log

```
[2019-05-10 08:30:02] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/myusername/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/03eb4921b9d19cdc3d1a531fe41b1069.png" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/home/myusername/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/03eb4921b9d19cdc3d1a531fe41b1069.png): Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/myusername/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/03eb4921b9d19cdc3d1a531fe41b1069.png\" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/home/myusername/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/03eb4921b9d19cdc3d1a531fe41b1069.png): Permission denied at /home/myusername/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382)"} []
```

how can i resolve these issue?

Comment: update file path in question for categories_searchresult.phtml